# how to adjust the height of the header and navigation bar in adminLTE template?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry to disturbs you guy but I really need help in this since I'm not a good css coder. So, I have been using adminLTE template for my project and now I want to insert my company logo into the navigation bar/header. Now, I have successfully inserted the logo and it can be viewed but for now, I want to increase the size of my logo. When I increase the size however, the navigation bar looked the same causing the logo to be shown only half.
Here is what I mean.

[image]

and here is my header code.

```html
  <header class="main-header">
  <div>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="index.php" class="logo">
   
     <span class="logo-mini"><img src="uploads/office/britay.png" class="brandlogo-image" alt="Brand Logo"></span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
     <span class="logo-lg"><img src="uploads/office/britay.png" class="brandlogo-image" alt="Brand Logo"><strong>Britay Asia</strong></span>
    </a>
 
 </div>
 
 <div>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" >
      <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="jobs.php">Jobs</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="candidate.php">Candidates</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#about">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <?php if(empty($_SESSION['id_user']) && empty($_SESSION['id_company'])) { ?>
          <li>
            <a href="login-candidates.php">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="register-candidates.php">Sign Up</a>
          </li>  
          <?php } else { 

            if(isset($_SESSION['id_user'])) { 
          ?>        
          <li>
            <a href="user/index.php">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <?php
          } else if(isset($_SESSION['id_company'])) { 
          ?>        
          <li>
            <a href="company/index.php">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
          <li>
            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
 </div>
  </header>
```

So, how can I alter my css so that the size of the header and navigation bar can be increased? And once again, I used the template of adminLTE:https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Any guidance is greatly appreciated and sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm suck at doing front-end, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<nav ...  style="height:100px">
```

add this style directly and change the value (height:100px or height:300px) according to your liking

UPDATE:
look for the "**logo**" class near "**main-header**" class and try to proceed with the following

```
<a class="logo" style="height:100px">
     <img ... height="100px">
</a>
```

Comment: It does help but my logo is still shown as half and now it shows half blue and half black